# Java cannot access Runtime Annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I encountered a problem with my self made annotations.

I have an Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Persistence {
    String value();
}
```

A class

```
public class TestOne extends PersistentObjectParent {    
@Persistence("someField") String foo = "bar";}
```

And I try to access all fields marked as @Persistence with a method declared in TestOnes superclass:

```
for(Field f : this.getClass.getDeclaredFields()){
    if(!f.isAnnotationPresent(Persistence.class)){
        continue;
    }
    //do something with f
}
```

As much as I read here Java should keep my Annotation since it's marked as Runtime. But the fields yield no annotations during runtime and my code always falls into the if block.

Could somebody point out where I went wrong?

Thank you

PS: The for-loop above is invoked like this:

```
TestOne p = new TestOne()
//...
p.save() //this is where the for-loop is started
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid question (this comment, not yours), but: Are you sure you're looking at the right class? (does `this.getClass()` return TestOne.class?)

Comment: this.getClass is called in a superclass of TestOne but returns TestOne. The field foo is present but without it's annotation

Comment: Where are you accessing the fields (for loop), i hope it is in sub class. (TestOne)?

Comment: I declared a method in the superclass  but the method is executed from the subclass.

Comment: you invoked the method from main() right , did you create an object of superclass OR subclass while accessing the method (which class object you accessed the method on?)

Comment: Tip 1: print field.getDeclaredAnnotations,  Tip 2: verify Persistence is your annotation, not javax.Persistence  Tip 3: Verify that project build classes are actual and contain the annotations

Comment: 1st: prints [Ljava.lang.annotation.Annotation;@368102c8. 2nd: yes they're mine in all classes using them. 3rd: all classes are compiled freshly. Problem still remains. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: @Steffn I'd print out `Arrays.toString( field.getDeclaredAnnotations() );` instead.

Comment: And there it is. I have no idea why but Arrays.toList(f.getDeclaredAnnotations()) returns the annotations as excpected

Comment: Have you tried using `getFields()` instead of `getDeclaredFields()`?

Answer (score 0):

I brought shame upon me ._.

Everything works just fine. I made a wrong assumption in my unit tests and became confused because the annotations didn't show up in debug mode.

Thank you all for your help and time

Comment: moral: if something is broken, it's most likely not java